# Case-insensitive GROUP BY along with primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Rails app where I want to retrieve some search suggestions based upon a string typed in by the user, say `foo`.

In short, I want to select all previous searches from the Postgres database matching the string `foo%`, group them on `query` (case insensitive) and include the column counting the number of times that `query` has been searched for. Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT MIN(searches.query),COUNT(*) AS hits FROM searches GROUP BY LOWER(query) ORDER BY hits DESC;
```

This gives me an error from Rails, since I did not include `id` in my custom select. But if I change my query to

```
SELECT MIN(query),id,COUNT(*) AS hits FROM searches WHERE query LIKE 'foo%' GROUP BY LOWER(query),id ORDER BY hits DESC;
```

The error from Rails is gone, but now the grouping doesn't work and I end up with duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `select_rows`:

```
Search.connection.select_rows("SELECT MIN(searches.query),
                               COUNT(*) AS hits 
                               FROM searches 
                               GROUP BY LOWER(query) 
                               ORDER BY hits DESC")
```

Which would return an array of arrays with elements matching the order of the columns selected.